# How to activate conda on Virtual machine using python automatically

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtual-machine, virtualenv, azure-virtual-machine

How to activate conda on a Virtual machine using python automatically
in ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these commands in the server shell

```
# Step 1: Prerequisites
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sha256sum wget

# Step 2: Update Your System
sudo apt upgrade

# Step 3: Download Anaconda
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh

# Step 4: Install Anaconda
sudo bash Anaconda3-2022.10-Linux-x86_64.sh

# Step 5: Activate the Installation
source ~/.bashrc

# Step 6: Check Info
conda info
```

More info: https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-anaconda-3-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa/

Hope this helps!